# Android: No activity found to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I used a lot of times Intents and they worked all the time, but with this code:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {



       int min = 1;
       int max = idmax;
       Random r = new Random();
       final int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        text= inviaDati(String.valueOf(i1));
                        splited =  text.toString().split("\\s+");//null array

                        type=splited[1]; //image, video, ecc
                        link=splited[2];




                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

       thread.start(); 


      if (type!=null)
      {

       if (type.equals("image"))
      {


       Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
       startActivity(browserIntent);
      }
      }
   }
```

});

It give me a: No activity found to handle intent
What can I do?
Thanks in advance

N.B: Other functions are working well

Comment: Your intent is working fine, do your mobile having browser ???

Comment: Can it be a problem of my emulator? :o

Comment: Yup try it with real device, sure it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change `Uri.parse(...)` to `browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse...)` on the line where you set stackoverflow as your target.